# Can I upgrade to 16.04 without using the software updater and keeping all my data intact?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, update-manager, lts

I'm on 14.04 and the software updater shows no update available.
Can I manually download the images and install them but without losing all my data?

Comment: The updater will show an available upgrade when 16.04.1 is released.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `sudo update-manager -d` That should get you to where you want You may have to run `sudo do-release-upgrade` too

As the other post mentioned ... you may have to go into the sources and change it. If you change it to `any new version` then run the above commands it should show the update. If you choose `long term support` it may not show. His way may also may also work since he is using the `Check if a new Ubuntu release is available` .. my method  uses `Check if upgrading to the latest devel release  is possible` For some reason sometimes the "new Ubuntu release" doesn't seem to show for me .. so if his method  doesn't work you can try mine .. one of them should definitely get the update to show

Answer (score 1):

You want to ensure that in the update manager settings, on the updates tab, where it says

> Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:

That you have `For long-term support versions` selected.

With that setting active run `sudo update-manager -c` to check if a new distribution release is available